# ListBoxFor with single selection in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using latest MVC5. **I want to use a ListBox NOT a DropDown.** The decision which control to use is not single/multiple selection decision.

Thats the error I get:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when multiple selection is allowed.

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   // @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedCompanyId, new SelectList(Model.Companies, "CompanyId", "Address"), new { @id = "CompanyListBox" })
}
```

**But how can I remove the multiple selection?** jQuery does not help here as the razor exception is first raised before the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#CompanyListBox").removeAttr('multiple');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a DropDownListFor and set the "size" attribute to be the number of visible items you want.

For example

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(x => x.SelectedCompanyId, new SelectList(Model.Companies, "CompanyId", "Address"), new { @id = "CompanyListBox", @size=10 })
```

Will display a "listbox" with 10 visible items.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use the `ListBoxFor` helper with `IEnumerable<T>` properties. In your example, if `SelectedCompanyId` is not an `IEnumerable<T>` it simply won't work. The `ListBoxFor` helper is designed to be used for multiple selections. Also if you remove the `multiple="multiple"` attribute using javascript, it's the same as if you were using a `DropDownListFor` helper.